# "ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException:" on archiving with XCFramwork, Bitcode enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, bitcode, xcframework

I am unable to archive the ipa when selecting "Rebuild from bitcode" export option, getting the following error

```
ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException: $ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/bitcode-build-tool
-v -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
-
```

Note:- I checked all my dependency frameworks are of .xcframework, supporting Bitcode.

Could anyone help me here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, I want to clarify myself that, should I enable "Rebuild from bitcode" option while releasing for enterprise or internal testing. As per my understanding, Apple Appstore rebuilds the app from bitcode, if we have uploaded the ipa with just Bitcode enabled. should I checkmark  "Rebuild from bitcode" option while releasing to Appstore?

Comment: I also had this issue. My workaround was to turn off Bitcode in in Targets > Build Settings > Enable Bitcode. I'd like to know why it doesn't work for when Bitcode is enabled though.

Comment: @Ganeshpatro have you found a solution to your issue? I've faced similar one, so any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

We've got similar issue, which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077795/ios-macos-app-distribution-failed-while-using-framework-after-upgrading-xcode12).
So long story short, there were LLVM instrumentation included, which prevents AppStore processing. I've written a whole blog about [XCode 12 and BigSur issues with XCFramework](https://blog.scichart.com/xcframework-xcode-12-and-bigsur-issues/).

To sum up, here is a few required steps to make sure while creating `XCFramework` for distribution:

- Using archive builds is a **MUST**, release build isn't enough
- `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` must be set to `YES`
- `SKIP_INSTALL`  must be set to `NO`
- `GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = NO` to turn off GCC instrumentation and remove them from the binary
- `CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE = NO` to turn off code coverage tools from the binary

Having all of the above helped to solve our preparing and distribution problem and hopefully save you some time if you happened to face same issues as we did.

Comment: Didn't help me :(

Answer (score 1):

Got exact same issue,

```
ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException: 
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3...
......

Status: pid 52712 exit 1
Stdout:
    SDK path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms
/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk
```

The reason it was generated was, I had `bitcode enabled` at `production target` but other targets ( `share-extension`, `debug`, `share-extension-debug` ) and `project level bitcode` was set to `No`.

When I enabled all, it worked for me.

Note that, all frameworks and binary I dependant on had bitcode present.